# Why can I not access the second level of this array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, json

Recently, [with help from the Stack Oveflow community](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18633326/184108), I learned how to work with JSON data that I got from the Google API. So, I thought I had a grasp on how to do roughly the same kind of action with JSON data from Blogger, again using the Google API.

However, it's been driving me crazy. I can't seem to get a handle on how to get at the right level of the array that I need.

What I am trying to do is get a selection of blog posts and then cherry pick out information and display it. Should be straight forward.

Right now my blog has **only three test entries**. I want to see if I can loop through the array I create from the JSON to display data. If I use this code:

```
$recentBlog = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/posts?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", true));

foreach ($recentBlog as $item)
{
    var_dump($item[0]);
}
```

... then I get data the first item *only* from the array. This makes sense to me. I looped through the array, but on each call, I only asked for the first item at the `0` position.

So I thought I would do this:

```
$recentBlog = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/posts?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", true));

$count = 0;
foreach ($recentBlog as $item)
{
    var_dump($item[$count]);
    $count = $count + 1;
}
```

... but I get the second and third item only. I do *not* get the first item anymore.

What is wrong with my code?

If it helps, this is [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using#RetrievingPostsForABlog) about the format of the JSON that I get back.

Comment: Maybe that's a stupid question, but have you tried to print_r the $recentBlog variable and see what's the structure of the array? Is it correct and the second loop not working or..? The second loop should get the first post of the first item, the second post of the second item and the third post of the third item, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have a wrong parenthesis in your JSON decoding call:

```
$recentBlog = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://[...]"), true);
```

Note that I moved one parenthesis directly behind the `file_get_contents()` function. This way `json_decode()` will return you an iterable array.

Comment: Wouldn't that have resulted in a syntax error instead of an empty array?

Comment: You're probably right. If the API does output a JSON array as root element, PHP will convert that to an array and the `foreach` loop will work nonetheless.

Comment: Well, you are certainly right! As it's stated in the cited docs, the API will return an object so my answer should not be the key.

Comment: Nice catch! I was tricked because the way I had it didn't trigger any syntax errors. I might never have caught that on my own.

Answer (score 0):

You get the response like below. If you want to loop the blog entries you have to loop `$recentBlog['items']` in foreach.

```
foreach ($recentBlog['items'] as $item)
{
    var_dump($item);
}
```

**Response:**

```
{
      "kind": "blogger#postList",
      "nextPageToken": "CgkIChiAkceVjiYQ0b2SAQ",
      "prevPageToken": "CgkIChDBwrK3mCYQ0b2SAQ",
      "items": [
        {
          "kind": "blogger#post",
          "id": "7706273476706534553",
          "blog": {
            "id": "2399953"
          },
          "published": "2011-08-01T19:58:00.000Z",
          "updated": "2011-08-01T19:58:51.947Z",
          "url": "http://buzz.blogger.com/2011/08/latest-updates-august-1st.html",
          "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/2399953/posts/7706273476706534553",
          "title": "Latest updates, August 1st",
          "content": "elided for readability",
          "author": {
            "id": "401465483996",
            "displayName": "Brett Wiltshire",
            "url": "http://www.blogger.com/profile/01430672582309320414",
            "image": {
              "url": "http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_YA50adQ-7vQ/S1gfR_6ufpI/AAAAAAAAAAk/1ErJGgRWZDg/S45/brett.png"
             }
          },
          "replies": {
            "totalItems": "0",
            "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/2399953/posts/7706273476706534553/comments"
          }
        },
        {
          "kind": "blogger#post",
          "id": "6069922188027612413",
          elided for readability
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, but the PHP code you suggest returns nothing.

Comment: can you give us the output of print_r($recentBlog);